# Missing WatchKit Extension in Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode, watchkit

I would like to integrate a watchOS extension into my iOS project. I set up the AppleWatch integration via File -> New -> Target -> watchOS -> App. Then can see WatchKitApp via a separate folder but not the WatchKitExtension.
I'm using Xcode 14 and compiling my project on iOS 16, do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you have any luck on solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Xcode 14 WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension are combined into a single target.

> Xcode 14 includes a default template for watchOS apps that combines
> the WatchKit App and WatchKit App Extension targets into a single
> Watch App target, simplifying code, asset, and localization
> management. You can deploy single-target watchOS apps to watchOS 7 and
> later. (83222217)

Source: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes

Comment: And where do I specify the CLKComplicationDataSource? Seems like their docs re not updated.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/clockkit/creating_complications_for_your_watchos_app/enabling_complications_for_your_watchos_app

Comment: Likewise I am trying to figure out where to "enable your WatchKit extension’s Background Modes capability and select your app’s session type" in this brave new extension-less world...